# php if statement relating to the url address

Tags: php

Say my URL address is www.example.com

I want to have an if statement in my script such that the test condition is true if the url is www.example.com and false if it is anything else e.g. www.example.com/test or www.example.com?var=3&function=7.

How do I achieve this? And will it add much overhead to the loading of the webpage? As I will have this if statement on the front page of the website.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will add an insignificant amount of load time, as it's just parsing some header information.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] // The host (e.g. www.example.com)
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] // The URI (e.g. /something.php or /something.php?this=true)
```

And to implement:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != "www.domain.com") // Do something
```

Comment: The information gets parsed even if he's not requesting it. So there's no overhead at all (except evaluating the if-statement of course).

Comment: That's correct, I guess there is always accessing the array.. but yeah, pretty much no measurable difference

Answer (score 1):

Testing to see if you have any extra parameters can be done like this:

```
if(count($_GET) > 0) { /* parameters exist */ }
```

However, to test if the browser is pointing to `/example`, you will have to employ some URL rewriting, as it not pointing to your php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mod_rewrite on:

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] == 'http://www.example.com' && !$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
```

There should be no noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: that should be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and it will be `/index.php` or what have you. It will not contain the host and URL scheme.

Comment: @prodigitalson `script_uri` is available with mod_rewrite.